# Question about Non-isolated Buck Converter

Tags: mosfet, diodes, buck, zener, converter

I have a tutorial problem about buck converter with MOSFET, anyone can help?

During the test of the non-isolated buck converter (see the circuit below), when we measure the gate signal, there is an output current from the power supply even without applying the gate voltage to the MOSFET ? Please explain the reason and give one solution.

I suggest the problem is the Zener diode or reverse current, but have no ideas at the moment.

[image: Buck converter with MOSFET]

Comment: D1 is a Schottky diode and not a zener. Also what is the part number for the specific mosfet. Also, please explain your measurement method.

Comment: Where are you measuring that current?   If you're measuring the current through the load attached to Vout, then the circuit is working as it should:  The inductor will resist change in current and become a temporary current source when the MOSFET is off. D1 (Schottky, not Zener) will complete the circuit that allows the inductor and load to conduct when the transistor is off.

Comment: any solution for the reverse current?

Comment: I meant how to settle this phenomenon? From the problem requested, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are sure there is no translation error? Because it sounds like why there is current even when the MOSFET is closed (Vgs = 0). If so, it's because inductor does not change its current instantly, instead it keeps current flowing all the time, and the mesh closes through the diode.

Comment: I just copied it from the tutorial notes, the question is asking why there is current even when the MOSFET is closed (Vgs = 0),

Comment: Then i think you got your answer

Comment: so any solution to change this phenomenon?

Comment: Why would you want to change it? It's a basic property of a buck converter

Comment: By the way, maybe you need a solution as electrical values. If so, voltage on switching node is - 0.5V, current on diode and inductor is decreasing, so average is the load current.

Comment: any improvements or methods to reduce the reverse current? Change the diode? I am so stupid...BTW, many thanks to all of you

Comment: It's not reverse current. It's current to same direction, just instead mosfet it flows through the diode.

Comment: I meant how to answer the question? Many thanks to all of you

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeing an output current and \$V_{gs}\$ is truly 0V, your MOSFET is probably either dead, wired wrong, or both. And a zener is not suitable as a catch diode. Replace it with a Shottky diode like shown.

Comment: It should be Shottky diode, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Zero Gate Voltage Drain Current is shown in datasheets as \$I_{DSS}\$ = 1uA typ, 100uA max for some devices.

If you measured more than this, then recheck your layout and measurement methods.

Comment: any solution for this problem?

Comment: any test results?

Comment: only 1 page for this question, it should be related to Rectifier, right?

Comment: I think the tutor only expect me to give some brief explanation and solution

Comment: " there is an output current from the power supply " means nothing to me. V, I results mean something.